# How to do replace with wildcards in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, replace, wildcard

I'm trying to replace a bunch of strings in a SQLite database.

I want to remove `CHECKCARD \d\d\d\d` (in regex notation) from the beginning.

Does the `replace` for SQLite have this feature?

I.e.,
`CHECKCARD 1215 AA BB CC` should become `AA BB CC`

`CHECKCARD 0715 DD EE` should become `DD EE`

I tried

`update ZUSERPAYEE set ZNAME = replace (ZNAME,"CHECKCARD ____ ","");`

but that did not work.

I need it to be a one-line command ... so I can run from Terminal on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite `substr()` function should be your savior here:

```
UPDATE ZUSERPAYEE
SET ZNAME = substr(ZNAME, 16)
WHERE ZNAME LIKE "CHECKCARD %"
```

This will find any row where ZNAME begins with `CHECKCARD`, and replace the value of ZNAME with the substring from the sixteenth character (i.e. after `CHECKCARD ####`) to the end.

[More on SQLite core functions, including a surprisingly featureful set of string handling functions.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

Comment: Let me be the one to push you over 2,000 reputation! Thanks

Comment: @Ze'ev Why, thank you, and I'm glad to have been of help to you!

Comment: can the WHERE clause come before the SET clause? And can the SET and WHERE be lowercase? Just curious.

Comment: @Ze'ev The WHERE clause is required to follow the SET clause; in general, each type of SQL query or statement has its own required order for the clauses it accepts, and your database engine's manual will be of help there. Neither those nor any other SQL keywords is case-sensitive; I usually prefer upper-case SQL keywords and lower-case table and field names, but if you want to use the opposite convention, it'll work just as well. (It's a lot less common in practice, though, so you might consider adopting the uppercase-keyword-lowercase-name convention purely on the basis of its near ubiquity.)